# Mandar correo cuando se cambia una celda en especifico

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy buscando un poco de ayuda con un proyecto "simple" a primera vista
Para ser mas especifico necesito, que me llegue un correo cuando y solo cuando alguien modifique una celda de la columna "G" y me diga, quien fue, a que hora y que le modificó. Esta es la columna que quiero estar supervisando

```
function onEdit(e)
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() == "ABRIL- 2019") //"order data" is the name of the 
sheet where you want to run this script.
{
var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Marca temporal") + 1;
var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("Empresa") + 1;
if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == orderCol)
{
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
  }
 }
}
```

Con ese codigo de arriba cuando alguien escribe en "empresa" en la columna "Marca temporal" se pone en automatico la fecha y la hora de esa modificacion.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name!='ABRIL-2019')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==5) {
    var user=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    if(user) {
      MailApp.sendEmail('mmmm@mmm.com', 'ultima modificacion', 'Test trigger: ' + user);
    }
  }
}
```

Y con esta funcion deberia de mandarme un correo a la direccion deseada diciendome el nombre de la persona que modifico manualmente la columna "Marca Temporal" y que le cambio.

Mi problema es que simplemente no envia nada y no se activa, no logro hacer que me mande correo, ese es mi problema con esta funcion, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida. En este sitio son mejor recibidas las preguntas que incluyen el código como texto, no como imagen. Por favor, reemplaza la imagen por el código correspondiente, además indica que es lo que hace tu código, dónde te has atorado y si ocurre un mensaje de error incluye este textualmente.

Comment: Ya esta, muchisimas gracias por su atencion

Comment: Bastante mejor la pregunta, tanto así,que ya tiene varios votos para reabrirla. Mientras se reabre, por favor agrega de forma breve si estás familiarizada con los conceptos de activadores siemples, los nombres de función reservados para ellos y cómo llamar funciones desde una función que se está ejecutando.

Comment: No habia ni podido tocar una PC, y tengo este pedido todavia estancado, no la verdad es que no tengo nada de experiencia en lo que respecta la programacion de google, pude hacer el de poner la hora con bastante ayuda, pero este caso en especifico no lo he podido resolver.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Una solución muy simplista es llamar la función que envía el email antes del último `}` de tu función onEdit

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Aquí el código original

  // Esta es la nueva línea
  myFunction(e);
}
```

## Explicación

`onEdit` es un nombre reservado para el activador simple "al editar" pero `myFunction` no lo es, por ello no se ejecuta de igual forma que `onEdit` y este debe ser llamado ya sea por la función onEdit o por medio de un activador instalable al editar o al cambiar.

Otra alternativa de solución es agregar el código entre `myFunction(e) {` y el último `}` dentro de los `{}` de `onEdit`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el primer codigo si esta bien, si me tira la hora en la celda que necesito, pero en el segundo codigo no logro hacer que se active, en ese es el que tengo mi problema, ahora bien, lo que me comenta es que si coloco "My function (e);}" en mi primer codigo, el segundo va a responder???

Comment: @LORENAVAZQUEZ Inténtalo y nos cuentas que pasó.